# The path '/node/7/' is either invalid or you do not have access to it

Tags: drupal

I am new to Drupal. Using Drupal7 just tried creating some main menus to my test site.

I tried creating a link 'about us' under the main menu. I just can't the set the path for the link.

```
Each time its throwing me an error: "The path '/node/7/' is either invalid or you do not have access to it."
```

The below is a screen shot of the error:

[image: error getting while creating a link in drupal 7]

I have googled a lot but nothing seems to be working my way!

Comment: did you try removing the forward slash at the beginning? Are you logged in as user 1?

Comment: What happen if you try http://172.10.1.73:8056//drupaltest/node/7/ ?

Comment: Try "node/7" without the first slash

Comment: @2pha yes I removed the forward slash at the beginning, still the same case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand what the error message means:

"The path '/node/7/' is either invalid or you do not have access to it"

It is saying that the page '/node/7' does not exist. You would have access because you are presumably logged in as the master administrator.

I don't know how you've managed to get to this point, it's really weird, but I suggest you do this:

1) Create a new or edit an existing piece of content (the content that you want to turn into this "test link").

2) Either set a path alias for this content, or take note of the 'node/x' number that you will see once you have saved it.

3) Return to your current screen and enter in either the alias that you set or the actual node/node-number for the content that you just created/edited.

Comment: Great going, completely understood made it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Path field :

```
node/7
```

For more info, usually node/X for your content-page created.

The URL must be the system URL (eg "node/1"), not an alias such as that generated by another module or one you've assigned to a node yourself.